# Stuck on two integration problems

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Item the first. Here my main question is, what do i do with the fraction out the front? Do i set it to zero and treat the rest like an improper integral?

Find the limit
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{1}{x^2} \int^x_1 \frac{t^2}{t+|\sin t|} dt\right).$$
Hint: L'Hopital.

And item the second. This one seems a little harder. I think that i need to utilise the integral mean value theorem as well as integration by parts, but any pointers here would be appreciated.

Given a continuous function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, show that
$$\int^x_0 \left(\int^t_0 f(u) du \right) dt = \int^x_0 f(u)(x - u) du,\qquad x\in\mathbb R.$$
Hint: parts.

Thank you for helping out with these

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Leibnitz's Rule for Differentiation under the Integral Sign.
$$\therefore \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\int_1^{x}\frac{t^2}{t+|\sin t|}dt}{x^2} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^2}{2x(x+|\sin x|)} = \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{2(1+\frac{|\sin x|}{x})} = \frac{1}{2}$$

---

For the second, let $1$ be the first function and $\int_0^{t}f(u)du$ be the second function.
Applying Integration by Parts,
$$\int_0^{x}({\int_0^{t}f(u)du})dt = t\int_0^{t}f(u)du|_0^x - \int_0^{x}tf(t)dt = x\int_0^{x}f(u)du-\int_0^{x}tf(t)dt$$
The integration variable is a dummy variable so we can replace $t$ by $u$ in the second integral. In the first, the integration is done with respect to $u$ so $x$ can be taken inside the integral giving us,
$$\int_0^{x}f(u)(x-u)du$$
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what i needed. Thanks again :)